# PHP array gets converted to int when using json_encode

Tags: php, json

I have the following array structure:

```
Array
(
    [t] => 812
    [0] => Array
    (
        [5] => 649
        [6] => 12
    )

    [2] => Array
    (
        [0] => 10
    )

    [3] => Array
    (
        [0] => 1
    )

    [4] => Array
    (
        [0] => 152
    )
)
```

At the moment all the array indexes (apart from t) are integers.

I want to convert it to it's JSON equivalent using json_encode(), but when I do so any of the arrays that have just one index in them (index 0) get converted into an integer rather than an array.

E.g.

```
[2] => Array
(
    [0] => 10
)
```

gets converted to..

```
{"2":[10]
```

instead of..

```
{"2":[0:10]
```

It'd be fine for the JSON to use string indexes rather than integers if that fixed the problem..

```
{"2":["0":10]}
```

Any thoughts on how I can solve this one?

Comment: `[]` is an array. `{}` is an object

Comment: Debugging sucks, but is necessary sometimes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are not converted to a single integer, but to an array with only one element!

In JSON square brackets `[]` denote an array, while curly brackets `{}` denote an object.

If you want to force `json_encode` to output objects, like in your example, you can choose the option `JSON_FORCE_OBJECT` ([see docu](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)):

```
$encoded = json_encode( yourArray, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT );
```

Comment: Perfect, did the trick nicely. I was all for iterating over the array and typecasting everything to strings! This is a much better solution.. thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Use `JSON_FORCE_OBJECT` flag in `json_encode`.